# What is the common solution for multiple datasources?

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

Greetings all 
In my spring application I will need to use hibernate with two different databases (PostgreSQL & MySQL) and I am not pretty good with configuration, so I need some guide about how to do so

I am using the following configuration for hibernate-postgresql

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.project.domain.myDomain</value>
            </list>

        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            </value>
        </property>


    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />

        <property name="url">
        <value>${db.url}</value> 
        </property>

        <property name="username" > 
        <value>${db.username}</value>
        </property>

        <property name="password">  
        <value>${db.password}</value>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

and in the DAO I make an autowire for the sessionFactory.

Comment: Do you need to persist the same entity in both databases, or do you need to get some entities from one database, and some from the other database? Like, "Person" is on MySQL, while "Order" is on PostgreSQL?

Comment: the second way, some entities in mysql and other entities in postgresql

Comment: Do you need to make changes to both database in a single transaction, or do you not need that?

Comment: no I don't need that, I will need separate transactions for each database.

Comment: can you please help me with the configuration problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724633/problem-with-using-two-datasources-with-hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to have to Data Sources with their one stack (SessionFactory, Hibernate Template, ect.). Then you can inject the HIbernate Tempolate you want to use in you business classes (or both if you want to access both DB at same time).

here is an example DAO with explicit config
    
    ...

```
<bean id="db2SessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
...
</bean>

<bean id="db1Dao" class="ch.sbb.uno.dao.hibernate.UnoHibernateDaoSupport" scope="prototype">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="db1SessionFactory" />  
</bean>

<bean id="db2Dao" class="ch.sbb.uno.dao.hibernate.UnoHibernateDaoSupport" scope="prototype">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="db2SessionFactory" />  
</bean>
```

Comment: so each datasource will have it's own sessionFactroy and it's own hibernate template, or they both will use the same one ?

Comment: but how to make autowireing this case, and does this approach has any drawbacks ?

Comment: yes when dealing with multiple beans of same type you can't use autowireing by type anymore. Try to inject explicitely

Comment: use the @Qualifier annotation and wire by name.

Comment: thanks guys, I tried the configuration but I am stuck here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724633/problem-with-using-two-datasources-with-hibernate

Comment: but is this approach have problems ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have two databases, and you want two-phase commit, you'd better be sure to use XA drivers for both.

Comment: if you're thinking of using MySQL and XA read this first http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xa-restrictions.html.  In my experience InnoDB XA support is not good

Answer (score 0):

You probably need XA drivers.

See below for an example

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Home